# Add a number to values of a column in Excel

Tags: excel

I have column in Excel colA. I want to add a number ,say 2000 ,  to all values in cell under colA . How can i do this ? The SUM function ends up totaling all the values on giving range of cells and the number to be added .

```
colA
----
8001
8002
8003
8004
8005
```

What I want

```
colA
----
10000
10001
10002
10003
10004
```

How to place formula on selected the cells ? Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Enter 2000 into any cell and copy it, then highlight the column that you want to add to and use `Paste Special -> Add`.